# docker - ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im trying to build a docker image on my Ubuntu machine using a docker file.

According to all the resources I read online, this should work, but it doesn't. even Docker discussions say this should be correct.

im getting this error

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I have posted my original code below with this line

```
COPY requirements.txt .
```

But I have tried below line as well without success

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

This is my folder structure

```
DIR - Docker
      docker-compose.yml

      SUB-DIR DevEnv
          Dockerfile.dev
          requirements.txt

      SUB-DIR Headless_Services
          Dockerfile.ultron_ms
          requirements.txt
```

this is my docker-compse.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  python1:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Jarvis-UltronBot 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
  python2:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Ultron-AlgoRoutine 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
version: '3'
services:
  python1:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Jarvis-UltronBot 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
  python2:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Ultron-AlgoRoutine 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
version: '3'
services:
  python1:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Jarvis-UltronBot 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
  python2:
    build:
      context: ./Headless_Services
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ultron_ms
    container_name: Ultron-AlgoRoutine 
    volumes:
      - /root/ultron:/ultron
    command: >
      sh -c "
      . /venv/bin/activate &&
      tail -f /dev/null
      "
```

this is my Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-azuretools.vscode-docker && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-python.python && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags && \
    code-server --install-extension ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow && \
    code-server --install-extension slightc.pip-manager

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN virtualenv venv && \
    . /venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["bash"]
```

this is Dockerfile.ultron_ms

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y screen virtualenv \
    && virtualenv venv \
    && . /venv/bin/activate \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN virtualenv venv && \
    . /venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: What command are you using to build?

Comment: docker-compose build

Comment: I have applied some sleep on the problem, the issue is that im trying to install the requiremements before copying the requirements and then trying to install them agian, thanks for the help tho, i will delete the question later today as it is useless to have this posted here, thanks